# How to get Selected Value in DropDownList from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to get selected value in dropdownlist.

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountRefNo, "Account Desc", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("AccountRefNo", ViewBag.AccountRefNo as SelectList, "Account Desc", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountRefNo)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartyID, "Party Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", ViewBag.TypeID as SelectList, "Party Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID)
    </div>
</div>
```

And, my Controller:

```
ViewBag.TypeID = new SelectList(db.PartyTypes, "TypeID", "TypeDesc", party.TypeID);

string[] codes = { "2.20.40.10", "3.50.10.20" };
ViewBag.AccountRefNo = new SelectList(db.ChartOfAccounts.Where(a => codes.Contains (a.AccountCode)), "AccountCode", "AccountDesc", party.AccountRefNo);
return View(party);
```

It seems it is OK but I don't know where the problem is. Both dropdownlists filling the lists but both are selecting their OptionLabel i.e selecting "Party Type" and "Account Desc" respectively.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you create your model in your controller?

Comment: what do the data types (classes) of PartyTypes and ChartOfAccounts look like?

Comment: It is in public ActionResult Edit(int? id) controller. I posted bellow that works now. thanks :)

Comment: Change the name of the `SelectList` property so that it does not match the name of the property you binding to - e.g. `ViewBag.AccountRefNoList = new SelectList(..)` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountRefNo, ViewBag.AccountRefNoList as SelectList, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

SelectList constructors' first parameter needs to take a collection of SelectListItem:

Try the following and it should work provided there is data (void of null refs on PartyTypes and ChartOfAccounts:

```
ViewBag.TypeID = new SelectList
    (
        db.PartyTypes.Select(m=>new SelectListItem {Text=m.TypeDesc, Value=m.TypeID})
        , "TypeID"
        , "TypeDesc"
        , party.TypeID
    );

ViewBag.AccountRefNo = new SelectList
    (
        db.ChartOfAccounts
          .Where(a => codes.Contains (a.AccountCode))
          .Select(m=>new SelectListItem({Text=m.AccountDesc, Value=m.AccountCode}))
        , "AccountCode"
        , "AccountDesc"
        , party.AccountRefNo //this maybe wrong 
    );
```

Also if ViewBag.AccountRefNo and party.AccountRefNo are the same type, then the last argument for the second SelectList constructor has to be incorrect.  The argument should be the selected value so most likely party.AccountCode?

Comment: Error: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'TypeID'.

Comment: the property TypeID was spelled as TypeId.  Now corrected it.

Comment: Actually, I changed TypeId to TypeID before doing but that gives me the error, Why I couldnt get. I changed in my code and this is also working I justs changed the selected parameter

ViewBag.TypeDesc = new SelectList(db.PartyTypes, "TypeID", "TypeDesc", party.PartyType.TypeDesc);

ViewBag.AccountDesc = new SelectList(db.ChartOfAccounts.Where(a => codes.Contains(a.AccountCode)), "AccountCode", "AccountDesc", party.ChartOfAccount.AccountDesc);

Answer (score 0):

This is in Edit controller and following worked.

```
string typeDescSelected = (from sub in db.PartyTypes
                   where sub.TypeID == party.TypeID
                   select sub.TypeDesc).First();
ViewBag.TypeDesc = new SelectList(db.PartyTypes, "TypeID", "TypeDesc", typeDescSelected);

string[] codes = { "2.20.40.10", "3.50.10.20" };
string accountDescSelected = (from sub in db.ChartOfAccounts
                           where sub.AccountCode == party.AccountRefNo
                           select sub.AccountDesc).First();
ViewBag.AccountDesc = new SelectList(db.ChartOfAccounts, "AccountCode", "AccountDesc", accountDescSelected);
return View(party);
```